# In tsql what does tablename(1) mean

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to analyze a query to extract the logic and I am seeing several select statements that use the syntax SELECT FROM tableName(1). Below is a few examples of this syntax being used. This is a fairly large insert statement so I am unable to post the entire query.

```
select nh.firm_code, nh.acct_num, nh.sub_code, b.amt
from nav_hist nh(1), breakpoints b
where nh.sales_load_id = b.schedule_id

select sum(weekdays.factor)
from calc_hist weekdays(1)
where weekdays.sys_date >= dateadd(dd, f.usr_num_days - 7, f.sys_date)
      and weekdays.sys_date < f.sys_date
      and c.firm_code = weekdays.firm_code
```

Does anyone know what the (1) means in the from statement?

Comment: The (1) is actually being suffixed to an alias. Testing this in SQL Server 2005 and 2012 results in a syntax error `Incorrect syntax near '1'`.

Comment: what rdbms are you seeing this in?

Comment: This is running without issue in SQL Server 2008. Weekdays is a valid tablename and not an alias.

Comment: If `weekdays` is a table and not an alias, what is `calc_hist`?

Comment: Isn't it that the table name is `calc_hist`, and it's being aliased as `weekdays`? At least, that how it appears from your question. What compat version is this database? Are you able to run those exact statements adhoc in SSMS?

Comment: @ p.campbell Yes I was mistaken weekdays is the alias.

Comment: Yes I am able to run these extract statements in SSMS. There doesn't seem to be a difference if I remove the (1).

Comment: I think `nav_hist` and `calc_hist` are key here. Once we know what exactly they are, I'm sure we'll be able to figure out the syntax.

Comment: My question is the (1) is not used as part of the alias name in the SELECT and WHERE statements of this query yet it is used in the FROM. Does anyone have any idea why this would be done or seen it before. Honestly I'm surprised that this syntax works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've done some digging and I think what's happening here is that you're actually using a Query Hint which is the '(1)'. This is intereprted as a INDEX Query hint, you can read more about these [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx).

According to documentation using this format without specificing WITH is deprecated and I cannot do this on 2008, but maybe you're using a different specific version or use some compatibility mode that affects this.

If you can provide more resources on queries containing these syntax, I'd be able to continue digging.

Here is what I get when I run on my server:

```
select * from sysobjects WITH (1)
--Warning: Index hints supplied for view 'sysobjects' will be ignored.
```

**EDIT**
I've looked further into this, ASSUMING that I'm right with my assumption and

```
SELECT 1 FROM TABLENAME(1)
```

Equals

```
SELECT 1 FROM TABLENAME WITH (1)
```

Then the below proves the point, when specifying an integer greater than the number of indexes available in the table will cause an exception. Take a look:

```
--Table sysjobs has 4 indexes
select * from msdb..sysjobs with (4)
--1 row affected
select * from msdb..sysjobs with (5)
--Msg 307, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
--Index ID 5 on table 'msdb..sysjobs' (specified in the FROM clause) does not exist.
```

Comment: in the link provided above you can find it under Arguments/With. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I'm still not 100% sure why the developer did this but at least I learned about what this means.

Comment: cool :) but, please note that (again, assuming I'm correct) it means that you're probably using the PK for your query. Maybe it does not produce the optimal query plan and you'd like to review it.